# How to go back with a SQL query if an error occurs?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I want to achieve accurate accounting in php and mysql. My code is working 100% fine.

For Debit:

```
$query = new QUERY(array('TABLE'=>'account_treasury_local_agent'));
$query->save($data);
```

And for Credit:

```
$query = new QUERY(array('TABLE'=>'account_treasury_headquarters'));
$query->save($data2);
```

The problem is, I want to revert whole transaction if there is an error in second function. I mean, I want to run this two queries together. Without debit, credit shouldn't be possible and vice versa.

**EDIT:**

I know, it's possible by means of TRANSACTION START, COMMIT, ROLLBACK. But, I have no idea, how to implement it with php.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using some specific php framework? If not, you should post the QUERY class, in order to know how to help you in edit the save function in order to have it use transactions

Comment: Using mysqli you have the functions `mysqli::begin_transaction` `mysqli::commit` and `mysqli::rollback` [link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php)

Answer (score 1):

To begin the transaction: `BEGIN` (or `START TRANSACTION`).

To commit: `COMMIT`.

To roll back: `ROLLBACK`.

That's all there is to it.

Comment: Thanks. But, Do you have any example in php?

Comment: `mysqli_query('BEGIN');` I suspect you're using a specific **framework** here and you're not sure how to run a query in that framework, but of course we can't guess that without knowing more about the framework. PHP itself has no special/complicated way of running a query.

Comment: I am using codeigniter. But the problem is, I am not using codeigniter's default db queries. I have built my own class to run queries. I think, I got the idea. I should start with a small example according to my query class.

Comment: Yeah, if it's your own custom query class we can't help much. Bottom line: however you'd normally execute a query using your class, execute those queries.